# Cannot save file after upgrade to 2007 VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have a sub which I call to save a file

```
Sub SaveToFile()

    maxr = Worksheets("List").Range("H1")

    Worksheets("List").Range("G1:AE" & maxr).Copy
```

Part of the code which is failing after an upgrade to 2007 is:

```
    With Application.FileSearch
        .LookIn = "Q:\Planning Tools\Reports\"
        .Filename = "Plan_" & ThisSaveTime & ".xls"
```

I receive a runtime error '445' object doesn't support this action, the code then continues below:

```
        If .Execute > 0 Then 'Existing Workbook
            Application.Workbooks.Open ("Q:\Planning Tools\Reports\Plan_" & ThisSaveTime & ".xls")
            ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Select
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Name = ThisPlanSaveName
        Else 'No existing Workbook, so add one
            Workbooks.Add 1
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Select
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Name = ThisPlanSaveName
        End If
   End With

    ......

End Sub
```

I am not sure which action is failing but can anyone see why?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft has removed **FileSearch** from the Excel 2007 Object Model

There are many possible replacements like **Dir** and using the **FileSystemObject**

try these links:

- [Mr Excel: Replacement class for FileSearch](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/268046-application-filesearch-gone-excel-2007-alternatives.html#post1317129)
- [MSDN Communities: Application.FileSearch in Excel 2007](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/isvvba/thread/a450830d-4fc3-4f4e-aee2-03f7994369d6)
- [Ozgrid Forums - Rplacement for FileSearch](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=164750&p=606015#post606015)
- [Ozgrid Forums - Application.FileSearch Replacement in Excel 2007](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=71409&p=369573#post369573)
- [Execl-IT.com: Replacement for FileSearch](http://www.excel-it.com/Excel%202007/2007_filesearch.htm)