# use vba to automate multiple xml to excel

Tags: xml, vba, excel, converters

alright, to start of: i am a complete VBA nitwit. I've been trying to crack this code for some hours now, and I think the best way to get further ánd learn how vba works, is calling in the troops. I hope no-one is offended by this.

This is what I am trying to do:
a) open all xml files in a folder, one by one
b) convert them to an excel file
c) then save them one by one as an excel file in another folder

the code I have so far is below:

```
Sub xmltoxl()
Dim fs As FileSearch
Dim i As Integer
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim s As Integer

Set fs = Application.FileSearch

With fs
    .LookIn = ThisWorkbook.Path
    .Filename = "*.xml"
    For i = 1 To .Execute()
        Set wbk = Workbooks.OpenXML(.FoundFiles(i))
        s = 1
   ChDir "C:\Users\Seeb\Desktop\Volkskrant\2013_archiefb"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename: (s & ".xls")
    s = s + 1
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Where does it fail?  What doesn't work?

Comment: (First of) it gives me a "Compile error: syntax error" on how I save the workbook (SaveAs line)

Comment: `FileSearch` has been removed from Excel since version 2007.  [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16459712/445425)

Comment: To use named parameters you need `:=` between the parameter name and the value so: `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=(s & ".xls")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested:

```
Sub xmltoxl()
Dim f As String
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim s As Integer

f = Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\*.xml")
s = 0

Do While Len(f)>0
    s = s + 1
    Set wbk = Workbooks.OpenXML(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & f)
    wbk.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\Seeb\Desktop\Volkskrant\2013_archiefb" & s & ".xls"
    wbk.Close False
    f = Dir() 
Loop


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

With a few changes, yes, it worked. At least, half way through (I'll just redo the second half). Thank you Tim.

```
Sub xmltoxl()
Dim f As String
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim s As Integer

f = Dir("C:\Users\Seeb\Desktop\Volkskrant\2013_archief" & "\*.xml")
s = 0

Do While Len(f) > 0
    s = s + 1
    Set wbk = Workbooks.OpenXML("C:\Users\Seeb\Desktop\Volkskrant\2013_archief" & "\" & f)
    wbk.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\Seeb\Desktop\Volkskrant\2013_archiefb\" & s & ".xls"
    wbk.Close False
    f = Dir()
Loop
```

End Sub